# Why would a SMD (spring mass damper) model of steel break down?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, modeling

Under what conditions would steel be able to be modelled as a 3D SMD model, and under what conditions would the model break down?

Comment: What property or behaviour of the steel do you want to model? Are you trying to model the (nonlinear? time dependent?) material properties of steel, or the behaviour of some particular structure made from steel?

Comment: @alephzero I'm describing the atomic structure of a steel of my choice (I haven't decided on a steel yet), and then showing how, under certain conditions, it would be modelled as an SMD model.